# Instantiating JavaFX classes in Clojure: SingleSelectionModel

Tags: clojure, javafx

I'm trying to instantiate SingleSelectionModel in clojure, based on "Pro JavaFX 2" book where they do the "cowbell" example.

From the repl, after appropriate importing of libs:

```
(SingleSelectionModel.)
InstantiationError javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel  cowbell.AudioModel/eval16031 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

This is the only constructor shown in the API docs; I can't find what this error means.

Any way to get this working?  No references to this came up on the google, except source code which is too deep to make any sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `cowbell` package/namespace?

Comment: in ...cowbell\src\clojure\cowbell\core.clj: `(ns cowbell.core...)`
in ...cowbell\src\clojure\cowbell\AudioModel.clj: `(ns cowbell.AudioModel...)`.  My project.clj has `:source-paths ["src/clojure"]` and `:java-source-paths ["src/java"]`, but for this example I'm trying to avoid Java completely and do the whole whing in Clojure, which is why I"m trying to instantiate SingleSelectionModel dircetly.

Comment: Can you show the entire REPL session leading up to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out SingleSelectionModel is an abstract class so it can't be instantiated.  I tried instantiating it in Java directly and got a similar error.  The documentation still defines a constructor however, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Abstract classes have constructors for their implementers to call from their constructors.